# Call to undefined method Closure::query()

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, mysqli, closures

I have the following Closure

```
$dbhProvider = function (){
    //Create connection.
    $instance = new \mysqli('localhost', USERNAME, PASSWORD, 'BLOG');
    return $instance;
};
```

And i have the following implementation

```
$mapper = new UserMapper($dbhProvider);
```

The `__constructor` of `UserMapper` looks like this

```
public function __construct($connection){
    $this->connection = $connection;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID=' . $this->user->getId();
    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
}
```

And when i exexute i have the following error 
 `Call to undefined method Closure::query()`. How can i do the properly implement so that the `$this->connection` instance variable holds the `mysqli` connection?

Comment: Which version of php do you use? [Closure::call](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) requires php version >= 7.

Comment: and two side notes: a) The code snippet doesn't show why you'd need Closure:call() b) Your not assiging a connection resource to $this->connection but a provider/factory; so the naming is ...suboptimal.

Comment: I use php 5.5.9. For your first note look my update. For your second, how can i assing a connection using this implementation?

Comment: title edited. call()->query()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function __construct($provider) {
    // invoke the closure/provider/factory
    // so that it returns the mysqli instance
    // which then gets assigned to $this->connection
    $this->connection = $provider();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID=' ....
}
```

Comment: this is the properly way for version below 7?

Comment: That's regardless of whether using php7 or below. Whether it's "proper" is another question, more regarding software design, e.g. doing the sql stuff  and calling `$this->user->getId()` in the constructor ( that's why I replaced it by ... ). And passing the database connection provider (closure) to the constructor may or may not be good design. The class is called `UserMapper`, so I'm inclined to put it in the "good" shelf ;-)